# Comparing two data frames to categorize

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes like below

I need to check if the code is present in the error so i can categorize it as per the category else will output NaN

Tried to use this but does not work

```
    print(test['Error'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x in c1['A1'] else 1))
```

```
         Error
0   sampletest1
1  sampletest22
2   sampletest3
3         Test4
4         Test5

     Code   Category
0  test1  cat1
1  test2  cat2
2  test3  cat3
```

I need the output to be

```
Error              Category
0   sampletest1    cat1
1  sampletest22    cat1
2   sampletest3    cat3
3         Test4    NaN
4         Test5    NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create dictionary, loop and set values matched by [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) for test substrings:

```
d = df2.set_index('Code')['Category']
print (d)
Code
test1    cat1
test2    cat2
test3    cat3
Name: Category, dtype: object

for k, v in d.items():
    df1.loc[df1['Error'].str.contains(k), 'Category'] = v
print (df1)
          Error Category
0   sampletest1     cat1
1  sampletest22     cat2
2   sampletest3     cat3
3         Test4      NaN
4         Test5      NaN
```

Another idea is use [`DataFrame.itertuples`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.itertuples.html):

```
for x in df2.itertuples():
    df1.loc[df1['Error'].str.contains(x.Code), 'Category'] = x.Category
```